# Testing truthiness in guards

Tags: elixir, truthiness, guard-clause

I can use guards to test if an argument is `true`:

```elixir
defmodule Truth do
  def true?(term) when term, do: "#{term} is true"
  def true?(term), do: "#{term} is not true"
end
```

This works as expected for boolean values:

```elixir
Truth.true?(true)
#=> "true is true"
Truth.true?(false)
#=> "false is not true"
```

But it cannot be tested for truthiness:

```elixir
Truth.true?(1)
#=> "1 is not true"
```

Is it possible to test for truthiness in guards? For example, can the following function be written using guards in the style of `true?/1` above?

```elixir
def truthy?(term) do
  if term, do: "#{term} is truthy", else: "#{term} is falsey"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official documentation for Guards](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/guards.html):

> Guards start with the `when` keyword, which is followed by a boolean expression.

So the expressions in guards must be boolean expressions.

Truthiness in elixir is defined by macros such as [`if/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#if/2). These macros are not available inside guards, so we need another way to convert the terms to boolean values.

We can see from the documentation (and [implementation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9.1/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3097)) of `if/2` that the definition of truthiness is that `false` and `nil` are falsey, everything else is truthy. So we can use that to implement our truthiness guards:

```elixir
defmodule Truth do
  defguard is_falsey(term) when term in [false, nil]
  defguard is_truthy(term) when not is_falsey(term)

  def truthy?(foo) when is_truthy(foo), do: "#{foo} is truthy"
  def truthy?(foo), do: "#{foo} is falsey"
end
```

This then works as expected:

```elixir
Truth.truthy?(true)
#=> "true is truthy"
Truth.truthy?(1)
#=> "1 is truthy"
Truth.truthy?(false)
#=> "false is falsey"
Truth.truthy?(nil)
#=> " is falsey"
```